# Wrong Favourite Tags being shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Occasionally the iPhone app will show me unanswered items for tags that I don't subscribe to. It looks like it's looking for ember.js tags but I don't follow that tag. I'm not sure why this is or what's going on.

[image: img]

A few minutes later it's right again.

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed with the next prod API build. (No update required.)

Caching was taking place on a method rather than an account level, so if someone looked at "Unanswered (My Tags)" just before you *and* none of the questions in that list had been modified, you saw their results.  Now this method will always be cached based on method and account.

Comment: Ah, the perills of caching...